# Не виден псевдоэлемент

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не виден псевдоэлемент `.top-nav ul li + li::before`?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  height: 538px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../img/header-bg.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

header .wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header-top {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}



.top-nav {
  float: left;
}

.top-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.top-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  color: #00af47;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.top-nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.top-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #54D287;
}

.top-nav ul li + li::before {
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  width: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="wrap">
   <div class="header-top">
    <div class="top-nav">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
```

Немного некорректно здесь сработало, но суть с псевдоэлементами в навигационном Ul верна.

Comment: какой псевдоэлемент?

Comment: .top-nav ul li + li::before

Answer (score 1):

Поменяй его позицию на relative .

Добавь

```
 border-left: 1px solid #146481;
```

А что твой псевдоэлемент должен делать?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  height: 538px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../img/header-bg.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

header .wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header-top {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}



.top-nav {
  float: left;
}

.top-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.top-nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  color: #00af47;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.top-nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.top-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #54D287;
}

.top-nav ul li + li::before {
  border-left: 1px solid #146481;
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  width: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="wrap">
   <div class="header-top">
    <div class="top-nav">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Нет, он должен делать просто вертикальные палочки между элементами списка. Но position не влияет на их появление никак...

Comment: так ( `border-left: 1px solid #146481;` )?..........Ответ обновлён

Comment: кстати да... можно ведь было просто бордером)) Я в другом проекте делал внизу, и там надо было особенно позиционировать, намного ниже. Поэтому делал при помощи псеводоэлемента. Но все равно очень странно, что так не работает...

Answer (score 0):

```
    .top-nav ul li {
+     position: relative;

    .top-nav ul li + li::before {
-     color: #fff;
+     background: #fff;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  height: 538px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../img/header-bg.png) no-repeat center center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

header .wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header-top {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}



.top-nav {
  float: left;
}

.top-nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.top-nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  color: #00af47;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.top-nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.top-nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #54D287;
}

.top-nav ul li + li::before {
  content: '';
  height: 20px;
  width: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="wrap">
   <div class="header-top">
    <div class="top-nav">
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Услуги</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
</body>
```